# Why is SQLite record not found?

Tags: objective-c, authentication, passwords

I am trying to program a username/password log in view controller, there is no errors, no warnings in my app but it always output out "match not found" even when i select  a username that already exist in my database..I'd really appreciate it if u could help
this is the code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths [0];
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bank.db"]];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_bankDb) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY, PASSWORD TEXT)";
        if (sqlite3_exec(_bankDb, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            _status.text= @"failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_bankDb);
    } else {
        _status.text=@"failed to open/create database";
    }

}


- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender {

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_bankDb) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE USERNAME=\"%@\"", _usernameTextField.text];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_bankDb, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *usernameField=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                _usernameTextField.text=usernameField;
                NSString *passwordField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) ];
                _passwordTextField.text=passwordField;
                _status.text=@"match found";

            } else {
                _status.text=@"match not found";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

        sqlite3_close(_bankDb);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that C++? Please include the language as a tag to the question.

Comment: Plain text passwords in the database?

Comment: yeah .. i am still new in this area

Answer (score 4):

You should do the following things,

1. look at `sqlite3_errmsg` values if any queries fail (e.g. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` does not return `SQLITE_OK` or `sqlite3_step` does not return either `SQLITE3_DONE` or `SQLITE3_ROW`);
2. Do not use `stringWithFormat` with your queries, but rather use `?` placeholders and bind values with `sqlite3_bind_text`

Thus:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_bankDb) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE USERNAME=?";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_bankDb, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert(0, @"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_bankDb));

    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [_usernameTextField.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert(0, @"bind failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_bankDb));

    int rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *usernameField=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        _usernameTextField.text=usernameField;
        NSString *passwordField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) ];
        _passwordTextField.text=passwordField;
        _status.text=@"match found";
    } else if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
        _status.text=@"match not found";
    } else {
        NSAssert(0, @"step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_bankDb));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    sqlite3_close(_bankDb);
}
```

If you're still failing with `match not found`, you should:

- examine the contents of `_usernameTextField.text` to make sure your `IBOutlet` is hooked up correctly.
- look at the contents of the database and make sure a record with the desired userid is found; you haven't shown us where you add the userid, so it's hard for us to diagnose why the userid in question was not found.

I must confess that the overall logic (just looking for matching records for that userid and populating the password field if you found the userid) looks highly suspect (you shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext, you certainly shouldn't be returning a password provided simply a userid), but I'm focusing solely on the tactical issue of why you're seeing `match not found` error message.

Comment: first of all, thank you Rob. I really appreciate it
second, i've done every thing u told me to do n i still get match not found, i double checked every thing before i even post this question and still the same.. i don't know what else to do.
plus about what you said concerning the "password" thing, i am new to this, n i actually don't know how to do it the right way, please can u or anyone else help me by giving me a helpful tutorials about this? i'd really appreciate it

Comment: @Shams7353 np. Regarding "match not found", perhaps you can update question that shows us the code in which you insert the userid record. (You show us how the table was created and how you're trying to read the userid, but never where the userid is created.) Have you looked at the db from the device/simulator (e.g. open it up in your Mac sqlite tool of choice) and confirmed that the userid record you're looking for is there? If you ran the app on the simulator, you can find the db in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ ...

Comment: (You may have to unhide Library w `chflags nohidden ~/Library` from the Terminal command line, if you haven't already.)

Comment: @Shams7353 Regarding the security/password question, I'd refer you to [Basic Security in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) on the Ray Wenderlich site.